# Inserting into a table with datetime column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create and use a table with a timestamp field. I tried creating it like this.

```
CREATE TABLE testdb(timestamp DATETIME, value INT NOT NULL)
```

I tried inserting into the table with these commands, but they both fail.

```
INSERT INTO testdb(TIMESTAMP_NOW, 3)
INSERT INTO testdb(GETDATE(), 3)
```

How do I create a table with a field for a timestamp, and how do I insert into that table?

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields. (A timestamp has _fields_ for hours, minutes etc.)

Comment: If you set a defailt `CREATE TABLE testdb(timestamp DATETIME not null default(current_timestamp), value INT NOT NULL)` then your timestamp column will be automatically filled in.

Comment: I would suggest using a column name of something other than "timestamp". That is a datatype and should be avoided as a column name. Also, a name should give you some indication of what it is. In this case, it is a time...but of what? DateCreated, DateUpdated something like that makes your name a whole lot better. It is not using a reserved word and it provides some clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax would have a column list and `values`:

```
INSERT INTO testdb (timestamp, value)
    VALUES (GETDATE(), 3);
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, except the ; at the end is not required.

Comment: @360man terminating SQL statements: The SQL Server documentation indicates that not terminating T-SQL statements with a semicolon is a deprecated feature. This means that the long-term goal is to enforce use of the semicolon in a future version of the product..